# Grails Controller won't persist object

Tags: mongodb, grails

Does the object being persisted by the controller need to have the same name as the controller? As in xobject and xobjectController? I am trying to persist a domain object for which I didn't create a matching name controller. I am trying to get it done from another controller but it doesn't save it. If I try to save an object from this controller that has the same class name as the controller then it works. Does this mean that every domain must have a matching controller and therefore one controller cannot work with multiple domain objects? I am using Mongdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you initializing the user variables based on form input? If so double check param names match between form and constructor.

Answer (score 1):

No not at all Controller and Domain object don't have to be same, it would help if you can share your code too.

Are you getting any error while saving the object? You can pass failOnError to forcefully fail your transaction in case of validation error.

```
xobject.save(failOnError: true)
```

Comment: I am not getting any error. That is what is confusing. Why would the controller save an object with the same domain name as itself and not another domain object with a different name. That is what so weird for me. See code in my "answer" below.